# sql like query fullname from three columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a textfield which takes in full name example: michael peter johnson
in my table i have three columns firstName , middlename and lastname
I have written this query but it returns empty

```
SELECT firstName,middleName,lastName
FROM staff
WHERE firstName LIKE "%michael peter johnson%"
OR middleName LIKE "%michael peter johnson%"
OR lastName LIKE "%michael peter johnson%"
```

if a user types in son it should display michael peter johnson, since son is contained in johnson.

thanks
my table : firstName has (michael)  middleName has (peter) lastName (johnson)

Comment: can you elaborate? its not very clear what is actually stored in the db.

Comment: nvm, I saw that you have three attributes. You need to use "LIKE" for one attribute value at a time, not all at once (see Dems answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're checking for any string that includes ***all*** of `michael peter johnson` in it.

You need three separate statements, with different comparisons...

```
WHERE
   firstName  Like '%michael%'
or middleName Like '%peter%'
or lastName   Like '%johnson%"
```

You *could* reverse the logic...

```
WHERE
   'michael peter johnson' LIKE '%' + firstName  +'%'
or 'michael peter johnson' LIKE '%' + middleName +'%'
or 'michael peter johnson' LIKE '%' + lastName   +'%'
```

You also give an example where the search is for `'son'`.  Your existing code *will* work for that.  It's just a 'problem' when you compare each individual part of the name against a parameter that has all of the name.

So, maybe you want both version together?

```
WHERE
   'michael peter johnson' LIKE '%' + firstName  +'%'
or 'michael peter johnson' LIKE '%' + middleName +'%'
or 'michael peter johnson' LIKE '%' + lastName   +'%'
or firstName  LIKE '%' + 'michael peter johnson' + '%'
or middelName LIKE '%' + 'michael peter johnson' + '%'
or lastName   LIKE '%' + 'michael peter johnson' + '%'
```

You just need to decide exactly what behaviour you want, and then work it through.

Comment: This still wouldn't match his partial entries, "son" as in his example.

Answer (score 9):

If I understand well, it currently works for parts of firstname/middlename/lastname, but not if you want to enter the full name.

To fix that, yOu can use concat, so it will always work:

```
select firstName,middleName,lastName 
from staff 
where concat(firstName, ' ', middlename, ' ', lastname) Like "%michael peter johnson%"
```

Comment: This combines the entries, which while it's implied by field names that it's what he wants, it's not what he's asking for - he wants *any* of them to match, not *all* of them, as your answer provides.

Comment: That's why I'm asking him at the begining of my question ;) I think this might be a bit easier to implement than exploding the values to test each fields: as any developper, I'm lazy and I don't provide anything more than specified :P /* just kidding */

Comment: @Tim, the user changed his question after haltabush responded.

Answer (score 1):

You want something along these lines:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE CONCAT(firstName, ' ', middleName, ' ', lastName) LIKE '%son%'
```

This will concatenate all the name fields into a single full name.

Hope this helps. You'll probably want to do a `LOWER()` on both sides of the equation. If I may add a comment, if you have a lot of names in your database this is not a particularly good way to do this.

Comment: Lower in not needen if the collation name finishes with _ci (ex utf8_general_ci, latin1_swedish_ci)

Comment: this will not work if the user types in michael peter johnson

Comment: @SoroushAtarod, why do you say that?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your query should look like this:

```
where CONCAT("%",firstName,"%") Like "michael peter johnson" 
or CONCAT("%",middleName,"%") Like "michael peter johnson" 
or CONCAT("%",lastName,"%") Like "michael peter johnson"
```

The reason is that LIKE matches the % against any number of characters, but does not remove characters - for example, `"test"` matches `"%es%"` but not `"%atesta%"`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you have the operands on the wrong side of the `LIKE` operator

Answer (score 1):

In sql:

```
firstName Like "%michael peter johnson%"
```

Means first name can start with any char then the string "michael peter johnson" should be in it and the last % means it can end with any char.
If you want to find johnson with son as input,  your test should be

```
select firstName,middleName,lastName 
from staff 
where firstName Like "%son%" 
  or middleName Like "%son%" 
  or lastName Like "%son%"
```

Or with regex:

```
select firstName,middleName,lastName 
from staff 
where firstName REGEXP ".*son.*" 
  or middleName REGEXP ".*son.*" 
  or lastName REGEXP ".*son.*"
```

Comment: It is normal, you asked for son as input. If your input can be any part of the name or the full name, you should concat the firstname, middlename and lastname column in your where clause like David Faber. And you replace your "%son%" with "%[the input]%" (do not include the brace [). You should also make sure there is only one space between each words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concat function in your query:

```
select firstName,middleName,lastName from staff where CONCAT(firstName,middleName,lastName) like ('%johnson%');
```